# Why does my site freeze after closing the modal (html, js)

Tags: javascript, html

I wait until the page is loaded and use the "DOMContentLoaded" method to add eventhandlers on some p tags. This works until I open and close the modal, then the page/js freezes. Why does it freeze?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_1">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>
        <p>Three</p>
    </div>
    <p id="open_modal">open the modal</p> 
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        let test = document.querySelector("#div_1")
        for (let i = 0; i < test.children.length; i++) {
            test.children[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
                console.log(test.children[i].innerHTML)
            });
        };
    });
    document.querySelector("#open_modal").addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (!document.querySelector("#modal")) {
                document.body.innerHTML += `
                    <div id="modal" style="display: block; position: fixed; padding-top: 200px; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)">
                    <div id="modal_content">
                        <span id="modal_close">&times;</span>
                        <p style="color: green;">Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
       document.querySelector("#modal_close").addEventListener("click", () => {
                document.querySelector("#modal").style.display = "none";
            });
            } else {
                document.querySelector("#modal").style.display = "block";
            };
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it normal for most of your code to be outside of the listener for `DOMContentLoaded` ?

Comment: This is just an abstract view of my code to point out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your **#open_modal** click handler. You are replacing content of document body with document.body.innerHTML += `...`, which mean that all your event bindings are destroyed, because there no more elements they are referenced to.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#replacing_the_contents_of_an_element

The solution can be

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div_1">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
    <p id="open_modal">open the modal</p>

    <div id="modal" style="display: none; position: fixed; z-index: -1; padding-top: 100px; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; 
                        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)">
                    <div id="modal_content">
                        <span id="modal_close">&times;</span>
                        <p style="color: green;">Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let test = document.querySelector('#div_1');
        for (let i = 0; i < test.children.length; i++) {
          test.children[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(test.children[i].innerHTML);
          });
        }
      });
      
      document.querySelector('#open_modal').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('#modal').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('#modal').style.zIndex = '1';
      });

      document.querySelector('#modal_close').addEventListener('click', () => {
          document.querySelector('#modal').style.display = 'none';
          document.querySelector('#modal').style.zIndex = '-1';
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer might be true but after reading some lines I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML which fits perfectly for this injection because it doesnt crash the "DOMContentLoaded" handler. Thanks!

Comment: For the implementing modal check the dialog element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog